# Import cycle on types

Tags: go, types, import, importerror

I've read questions on stackoverflow and articles on other sites, but still cannot solve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
package routing

import (
    "net/http"

    "bitbucket.org/codictive/ise/components/user"
)

// Route defines a component route structure.
type Route struct {
    Path        string
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Description string
    Handler     func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data TemplateData)
}

// TemplateData defines data structure which passed to component handlers and rendered to client.
type TemplateData struct {
    AppDomain   string
    Data        map[string]interface{}
    RequestPath string
    Route       Route
    User        *user.User
}
```

The template package's `Render` function used in handlers to render html template to client's browser:

```
package template

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "path"

    "bitbucket.org/codictive/ise/components/log"
    "bitbucket.org/codictive/ise/core/component/routing"
)

// Render executes given template to user's client with given data.
func Render(fp string, data routing.TemplateData, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    files := []string{
        "storage/templates/master.html",
        path.Join("storage/templates", fp),
    }

    tmpl, err := template.New("master.html").Funcs(funcs).ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("[Render] Template creation failed. (%v)", err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        log.Error("[Render] Template execution failed. (%v)", err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Every component has a dependency to routing package to define it's routes:

```
// Component defines application component structure.
type Component struct {
    Name   string
    Config interface{}
    Routes []routing.Route

    // Boot filters
    Before func()
    After  func()
}
```

and component handlers also use `routing.TemplateData`:

```
// indexHandler displays application homepage.
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data routing.TemplateData) {
}
```

So the code highly depends on `routing.TemplateData` which is my problem; Because `TemplateData` is also dependent on `routing.Route` and `user.User`:

- I could not make another package just for `TemplateData`; It just moves import cycle there.
- Also I think I can't use interfaces because the cycle is on types not functions.
- I can't move all this in one package.
- I do not want create single purpose packages (eg. `user/models`, `user/handlers`, ...) just to bypass the cycle, as possible.

What can I do to solve import cycle problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here with structure, so you'll need to make some changes. A few general guidelines:

- Try to have packages know the minimum about the world (only a few should import lots of others)
- Declare data structures or interfaces in the pkg where they are used
- Prefer simple interfaces (with just a few methods), and simple data structures
- Try to have packages never import packages above them, only siblings or children (not always possible, but a good guideline)

So looking at your problems:

1. Your components currently know about routes, but don't need to - they should expose handlers, and you can let the app or main package wire up handlers and the router. Handlers should not know how they are used.
2. Your router knows about templates and rendering, but doesn't need to, remove TemplateData from there, handlers should Render themselves by importing your template package and using it.
3. Your TemplateData knows about users but doesn't have to - I would remove this and reduce the render context to  Data map[string]interface{}, as the user could be added there and having it separate doesn't add much but does mean your template package has to know about your specific user type, which is bad.

These first three points are a question of removing dependencies that shouldn't exist - your packages are too interdependent.

4. Finally, and crucially, your components can't know about other components or you'll eventually hit a Handler that needs to import user, page, tag all together and can't because the tags handler also needs to import user, or users will have tags and tags will have users etc. To tackle this you *need* to separate your handlers from components somehow.

So listing possible layout solutions with an open mind (the best depends on the structure and complexity of your project):

- Put everything in one package (good for v. simple apps, not good for complex)
- Split by function (models, views, handlers etc) - I'm not so keen as means jumping around and splits up bits of components like users to separate models from handlers - this is a rails-like approach.
- Split by resource/component, but use sub-packages for handlers (my preferred option)

You are already splitting by resource to some extent (what you call components), so let's work with that. Here is an example layout (each entry is a package):

- server.go - (main calls app setup, runs server)
- app (sets up db, logging etc, links handlers to router, imports all)
- user (component)

  - handlers (user handlers)
  - assets  (user assets, js etc)
  - templates (user templates)
- page

  - handlers
  - assets
  - templates 
    ...

You say *I do not want create single purpose packages*, which you may feel this violates, but I suggest you try it out, I think it is closest to your suggested structure.

This keeps everything about users in one place, lets the page handlers pull in users or other resources as required, without polluting pages with information about users say - it forces you to keep components completely separate except in handlers, which are allowed to pull in multiple components which is often necessary. You can find an example of this sort of structure [here](https://github.com/kennygrant/gohackernews). This means only the app and handlers know about other packages, every other package can be completely self-contained (hence no change of cyclic dependencies).

The good news is once you've tackled these issues you'll find your packages are far more independent, this constraint (imposed to speed up compile times) is one of my favourite bits of Go as it also forces you to have quite a decoupled design.